# L1 Regularization for "lightgbm" engine in tidymodels

Tags: r, lightgbm, tidymodels, r-parsnip

How can I insert a regularization parameter in `tidymodels` for `boost_tree()`? In the normal `lightgbm` package there is the tuning parameter `lambda_l1`. I would like to use this in `tidymodels` as well.

I tried to code it like this, but I am unsure if I am doing right:

```
lgbm_model <-
        boost_tree(
            mode = "regression",
            # mtry = 1,               
            trees = tune(),           
            min_n = tune(),           
            tree_depth = tune(),       
            learn_rate = tune(),      
            loss_reduction = tune()   
        ) %>%
        set_engine("lightgbm", lambda = 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `lambda_l1` isn't a main argument for `boost_tree()`, you would indeed supply that argument to `set_engine()`. Supply it exactly as it is named in `lightgbm::lgb.train()` or it's `param` argument, using `lambda_l1`. The bonsai package, which implements support for the `"lightgbm"` engine with parsnip, will take care of passing that argument to the right place.

Your code would look something like this:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(bonsai)

lgb <-
  boost_tree(mode = "regression",) %>%
  set_engine("lightgbm", lambda_l1 = .9)

lgb_fit <- fit(lgb, mpg ~ ., mtcars)

lgb_fit
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> LightGBM Model (1 tree)
#> Objective: regression
#> Fitted to dataset with 10 columns
```

To confirm that `lambda_l1` was supplied as you intended, you can extract the underlying LightGBM fit and poke inside of it:

```r
lgb_fit_engine <- extract_fit_engine(lgb_fit)
lgb_fit_engine$params$lambda_l1
#> [1] 0.9
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-28 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

:)